# What is meant by "Exchange rate expectations are static" (In the Mundell-Fleming model)

Tags: macroeconomics

When I was studying the Mundell-Fleming Model, I came across the assumptions :

> 1- Exchange rate expectations are static
>
> 2- Capital mobility is less than perfect

I ended up with the following questions :

Q1) Does capital mobility less than perfect implies $r \ne r^{*}$ where $r$ is the domestic interest rate and $r^{*}$ is the foreign interest rate. Or does it mean $r \neq r^{*} + \delta S^{e}$ Which is the UIRP

Q2) What is meant by "exchange rate expectations are static"?

Comment: In the standard Mundell-Fleming model, capital mobility _is_ assumed perfect. You must be examining some variant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression "**Static Expectations**" unfortunately can be found to be used with two different meanings in the economics literature

**1)** The one apparently less used but used nevertheless is, for some variable $x$ that needs to be predicted while standing at period $t$ (the superscript $e$ denotes "expectation" in the general meaning of the term, without specifying how it is formed)

$$x^e_{t+1 |t} = b,  \;\;\; \forall\, t$$

where $b$ is some *constant*. This reflects the following attitude: agents are oblivious to any information accrual as time passes, they even ignore possible movements in the realized values of $x$, and if asked, they always think that "tomorrow" the value will be $b$ (perhaps a better way to describe such expectations would be "fixed expectations" rather than "static").

**2)** The other and most widely used meaning of "Static expectations" is

$$ x^e_{t+k |t} = x_t, k=1,2,...$$

i.e. "what is will continue to be".

In the Mundell-Fleming model, the expression is used with this meaning.

(I note that with this meaning, "Static Expectations" *coincide* with Rational Expectations when the $x$-variable follows a pure random walk -but again, in Static Expectations we do not specify how we arrive at the value we expect).

Given this, **imperfect capital mobility** would lead to the domestic interest rate being different in equilibrium from the international interest rate in the sense $i \neq i^*$, since the exchange rate is not expected to change. So the Uncovered Interest Rate Parity (in logarithmic terms) $i = i^*+\Delta s^e$ becomes under Static Expectations $i = i^*$, and stops to hold under imperfect capital mobility.